# rails, devise, rspec, capybara test failing when destroying a dependent of user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, devise, capybara

I am trying to make a test pass whereby when deleting a devise registration, the dependents of the user model are deleted. This is mainly a matter of curiosity as it seems to be working when done manually but I never pass up the opportunity to learn what I'm doing wrong.

Here's the set-up
user model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :projects, :dependent => :destroy

  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
end
```

project model:

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :conts
  has_many :models

  validates :name, presence: true
  after_validation :parameterize_and_underscore_name
end
```

And the failing test:

```
describe  "cancel account" do
  scenario "deletes all projects associated with user", :focus do
    # @user created in a prior before loop
    project = create(:project)
    @user.projects << project

    # both pass
    User.all.size.should == 1
    Project.all.size.should == 1

    # also passes
    User.find(1).projects.first.should == @project

    click_button "Cancel my account"

    # passes
    page.should have_content "Bye! Your account was successfully cancelled. We hope to see you again soon."

    # passes
    User.all.size.should == 0
    # fails
    Project.all.size.should == 0
  end
end
```

The failure message is:

```
Failure/Error: Project.all.size.should == 0
       expected: 0
            got: 1 (using ==)
```

As I said, when doing this manually, it does work the SQL generated is:

```
User Load (0.6ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = 1 ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
   (0.2ms)  BEGIN
  Project Load (3.9ms)  SELECT "projects".* FROM "projects" WHERE "projects"."user_id" = $1  [["user_id", 1]]
  SQL (0.5ms)  DELETE FROM "projects" WHERE "projects"."id" = $1  [["id", 1]]
  SQL (0.3ms)  DELETE FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1  [["id", 1]]
   (0.7ms)  COMMIT
```

So, is there some sort of Gotcha I should be aware of (or am I just completely in the wrong ballpark) or is this a bug I should make the developers aware of. If it is a bug, is it a bug associated with devise, rspec or capybara (how would I find out?)

**Notes:**

I have tried doing it with and without :js => true but this makes no difference

Comment: Your test look alright, your test.log says that the queries don't run?